# Laravel 4 : why did I get 2 different of 404 error page?

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

I'm using Laravel 4.2 framework for my website, and want it catch my 404 error correctly. My problem is that the server return a different 404 page when I try to open some bad link inside the public folder. Please give me some advice, thank you very much.

Folder structure:

```
 -- app
 -- bootstrap
 -- public
    --assets
    --packagespage
 -- vender
```

Normally, I set my 404 page like this:
[image]

When I tried http://localhost:8000/assets/some-name and http://localhost:8000/packages/some-name => new 404 page here: [image]